# Netbean stopped showing output after running 1GB XML for 30mins

Tags: xml, memory, extract, sax

I am running an SAX Parser in Netbean to extract 1GB of XML data and write into CSV file.

My program is running perfectly when I use test data of less then 1MB. The code runs displaying print outs that I expected and CSV files produced are correct.

So next I run my code with the 1GB XML. The code was running and displaying expected outputs for about 30mins (It was able to successfully read all the way to line 105439 in the XML),

after which, the Output just stopped showing. At the bottom of Netbean, it says the program is running, although the green bar kind of stopped flowing. This goes on for another half-an hour of nothingness

Because no error was displayed, I couldnt tell is it still reading the XML, or has the program hanged due to insufficient memory.

My code is 900 lines long. But here is a summary of how I wrote it:

I use Array to store the element, write into CSV, and reuse the Array again.

```
public static String authorArray[] = new String[2];
```

Set is used to check for duplicate Authors. Since there can be 1GB of Authors, Im not sure if authorSet might be the one causing memory problem.

```
public static Set<String> authorSet = new HashSet<String>();
```

Finally I used Hashmap to relate Author's name with ID to relate which book he wrote. Again there could be 1GB of Authors, so this will need to store a lot.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> authorNameIDMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

When I pre-maturely terminate the program, up to 6534 Authors were stored (only 20% of the entire XML authors)

Please help! I really want to know where the program lies. Thanks in advance

Comment: if you are talking about netbean's console then please check what is the maximum number of lines it can print or try to change the output location to some file instead of console

Comment: I tried commenting out the AuthorSet and surprisingly the program executes finish, although there are duplicated Authors. Is it because Set has a limited size it can store? Like up to 6534?

Comment: Set does not have duplicates and there is no such restriction on the size